# Perl: Use regex matched snippet as part of replacement

Tags: regex, perl

What I am looking to do is to use a Perl regex check, most likely a s///, to find a valid URL within a string and replace it with the linked version of that URL.

Example:

input: `blah blah www.duckduckgo.com blah bleh`

output: `blah blah <a href="www.duckduckgo.com">www.duckduckgo.com</a> blah bleh`

I don't have any example code, because I'm not entirely sure where to start. All I know is that I want it to look like this:

```
$string =~ s/[URL regex]/[Link replacement regex]/g
```

Thanks for reading.

Edit: As Miller pointed out, I'm not very descriptive, so I am going to include what I'm using as my URL finding regex.

```
\s[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[\w]{2,3}\s
```

Edit 2: Un-broke my regex

Comment: It sounds like you haven't spent any significant effort reading the documentation and looking for tutorials on this topic. I am happy to help someone out who is completely stuck with a problem, but I'm not inclined to spend the time to answer your question just to save you a bit of work.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't put a lot of effort into describing your data, which is necessary to know how restrictive the regex needs to be.

However, as a starting point perhaps looking for a list of word characters with at least one embedded period would be a sufficient requirement:

```
my $string = 'blah blah www.duckduckgo.com blah bleh';

$string =~ s{(\w+\.[\w.]+)}{<a href="$1">$1</a>}g;

print $string;
```

Outputs:

```
blah blah <a href="www.duckduckgo.com">www.duckduckgo.com</a> blah bleh
```

Comment: So, the previous match is stored in $1? That might be all I need, thanks. I'll try it out.

Comment: No, the previous match *isn't* stored in `$1`. Please read and understand [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Answer (score 0):

use [URI::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::Find) CPAN module. For your example, assuming schemaless URLs, this works:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use URI::Find::Schemeless;

my $finder = URI::Find::Schemeless->new( sub {
    my $uri = shift;
    return '<a href="' . $uri->as_string . '">' . $uri->host . '</a>';
});

my $string = 'blah blah www.duckduckgo.com blah bleh';
my $how_many_found = $finder->find(\$string);

print $string, "\n";
```

Prints:

```
blah blah <a href="http://www.duckduckgo.com">www.duckduckgo.com</a> blah bleh
```